# What's the difference between "x!" and "x"?

Tags: macos, vim, terminal

I've just started learning Vim and noticed that there's two ways to save and exit - `:x` and `:x!`. I've tried both, and both seem to do the exact same thing. Is there any significant difference between using the `!` and not using it?

Comment: First thing to do – always – is to look it up in the help: `:h :x`, which points you to `:h :wq`, which explains the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with `!` you can write changes to a file marked with `readonly`

You can create a readonly file (`set readonly`) , do some changes, then `:x`, you are gonna see the message.

`:h 'ro'` for details.

Answer (score 0):

vim do not let you do unespected things, such as write a read-only file, or edit a new file if  the current buffer as not been writing on disk.

But vim let you overwrite those permission with *!* :

```
:wq!
:edit! newfile
```